# Conversion failed after change column data type in sql-server

Tags: sql-server

In sql server v.17 I have a table with name `documents`. `document_number` column was `int`. I change its data type to `nvarchar(100)` using

```
ALTER TABLE documents
ALTER COLUMN document_number nvarchar(100);
```

After that when I want to update a row like this:

```
update [documents] set
    [document_number] = 'test' where [id] = 15826
```

I give below error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'test' to data type int.

But I don't have any idea why this error accurd.

**One more thing:** Also when I get column data-type

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
     TABLE_NAME = 'documents' AND 
     COLUMN_NAME = 'document_number'
```

Its return `nvarchar`.

Comment: There may be a trigger on the table. Please check if any exists.

Comment: @FarhadRahmanifard Thanks. Yes I had a trigger on table. Solved.

Comment: Learn this lesson well - the complete error message should have included the name of the trigger in it. When discussing errors in code, always post the complete and exact error message.